# c++ generate vertical 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

c++ vertical array 
how to create the output in vertical list.

i try so many times but it cant work.How exactly do I print it out for when I run it? I can't test it because I don't know how to print it out :/ But I feel like I have it wrong anyway. 
The sample Output should like this

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5-VrB_qbetVX2xRQ2ZIYkxzQWc/edit?usp=sharing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 5


int* getData (int* pAry, int arySize);
void selectSort (int* pAry, int* pLast);
void printData (int* pAry, int* pLast);
int* smallest (int* pAry, int* pLast);
void exchange (int* current, int* smallest);

int main (void)
{
    int ary[SIZE];
    int* pLast;

    pLast = getData (ary, SIZE);
    selectSort (ary, pLast);
    printData (ary, pLast);

    return 0;
}


int* getData (int* pAry, int arySize)
{
    int ioResult;
    int readCnt = 0;
    int* pFill = pAry;

    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter Number Please: ";
         ioResult = scanf("%d", pFill);
        if (ioResult == 1)
        {
            pFill++;
            readCnt++;
        }
    } while (ioResult == 1 && readCnt < arySize);


         cout<<"\n\nOriginal: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout<<*pAry++;


    return (--pFill);
}

void selectSort (int* pAry, int* pLast)
{
    int* pWalker;
    int* pSmallest;

    for (pWalker = pAry; pWalker < pLast; pWalker++)
    {
        pSmallest = smallest (pWalker, pLast);
        exchange (pWalker, pSmallest);
    }

    return;
}


int* smallest (int* pAry, int* pLast)
{
    int* pLooker;
    int* pSmallest;

    for (pSmallest = pAry, pLooker = pAry + 1;
        pLooker <= pLast;
        pLooker++)
        if (*pLooker < *pSmallest)
            pSmallest = pLooker;

    return pSmallest;
}


void exchange (int* current, int* smallest)
{
    int temp;

    //printf("This is the current value %d and this is the smallest value %d", *current, *smallest);

    temp = *smallest;
    *smallest = *current;
    *current = temp;

    return;
}


void printData (int* pAry, int* pLast)
{
    int nmbrPrt;
    int* pPrint;



    cout<<"\n\nAscending:\t Descending ";

    for (pPrint = pAry, nmbrPrt = 0;
        pPrint <= pLast;
        nmbrPrt++, pPrint++)
        cout<<"\n"<<*pPrint<<"\n<";


    for (pPrint = pLast, nmbrPrt = 0;
        pPrint >= pAry;
        nmbrPrt--, pPrint--)
    {
        cout<< *pPrint<<"\v";
    }


    cout<<"\n\nDone\n\n ";

    return;
}
```

Edit

```
 do
{
    cout<<"Enter how many times";
    cin>>SIZE;

    cout<<"Enter Number Please: ";
     ioResult = scanf("%d", pFill);
    if (ioResult == 1)
    {
        pFill++;
        readCnt++;
    }
} while (ioResult == 1 && readCnt < arySize);
```

How about this 2

```
 int ary[SIZE];
int sary[SIZE];
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it ?

Comment: You should store your list in 3 different arrays and print them out all together at the end.

Comment: the code can work but get this output 
original 1 1 1 1 1
descending 2 2 2 2 2  
how to store in 3 different way .

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** My answer is in pure C. If you want to do C++, I suggest you to use `std::vector` and `std::sort`

Try the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 5


void getData (int*);
void printData (int*, int*);
int compare(const void*,const void*);

int main (void)
{
  int array[SIZE];
  int sorted_array[SIZE];

  getData (array);
  memcpy(sorted_array, array, SIZE*sizeof(int));
  qsort(sorted_array, SIZE, sizeof(int), &compare);
  printData (array, sorted_array);

  return 0;
}


void getData (int* pAry)
{
  int ioResult;
  int readCnt = 0;
  int* pFill = pAry;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter Number Please: ");
    ioResult = scanf("%d", pFill);
    if (ioResult == 1)
    {
      pFill++;
      readCnt++;
    }
  } while (ioResult == 1 && readCnt < SIZE);
}

int compare(const void* pa,const void* pb)
{
  int a = *(int*)pa;
  int b = *(int*)pb;

  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  return 0;
}

void printData (int* pAry, int* pSAry)
{
  int i=0;
  printf("\n+--------------------------------+\n");
  printf("| Original | Ascending|Descending|\n");
  printf("+----------+----------+----------+\n");

  for (; i<SIZE; i++)
  {
    printf("|%10d|%10d|%10d|\n",pAry[i],pSAry[i],pSAry[SIZE-1-i]);
  }
  printf("+--------------------------------+\n");
}
```

Output with 12,15,14,5,8 :

```
+--------------------------------+
| Original | Ascending|Descending|
+----------+----------+----------+
|        12|         5|        15|
|        15|         8|        14|
|        14|        12|        12|
|         5|        14|         8|
|         8|        15|         5|
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: if using dynamic array ?

Comment: no problem, that will work. Replace `#define SIZE 5` by `int SIZE`, Modify the value of `SIZE` in `getData`. And allocate the arrays after `getData`.